# Cannot Deserilize Json Format

Tags: c#, json

I cannot deserilize this Json result

[image: Json Result]

I have this code for that

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, true))
                {
                    valor = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(valor)))
                {
                    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ApiData>));
                    List<ApiData> obj = (List<ApiData>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            throw;
        }
```

But the result obj is null

ApiData Example

```
    [DataContract]
    public class ApiData
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string coArt { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string artDes { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public string fechaReg { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public bool manjSer { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    }
```

Anyone can help me or tell me whats wrong with the code or format casting? thanks you

Comment: Please post the code for `ApiData`.

Comment: It looks like your JSON is not an array, but you are trying to deserialize it as a list.

Comment: I try in list, because in plain object ApiData doesn't work @shieldstroy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root JSON entity isn't a list, it's an object with name/value pairs, the first name being `0` and the values being instances of your `ApiData` class.  To deserialize this, you should use a `Dictionary<string, ApiData>` (or `Dictionary<int, ApiData>` if you are sure that only numbers appear as keys).

Thus:

```
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, ApiData>), new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true });
        var dict = (Dictionary<string, ApiData>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
```

Note that you must set [`DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.usesimpledictionaryformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to use [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parse dictionaries in this format -- and this setting is only available starting in .Net 4.5.